# Site packages in Python

Tags: python

So I have two sitepackage folders:

1. Under: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
2. Under: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages

Every time I do sudo easy_install module, Python installs it in (1).
Every time I try to import it from (1), Python can't find it.

Every time I move that module with copy and paste to (2), Python can find it.

Is there an elegant/regular way to make Python install it in the correct sitepackages?

Comment: this appears relevant: http://bugs.python.org/issue4865

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages` to your [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Comment: Thanks. Will try. In the bash.profile: What does ${PATH} mean in : PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Comment: Putting it on the Path did not help me. Is there anything else I can do ?

Comment: Yeah, don't add it to the PATH variable but to the PYTHONPATH one. (e.g: `PYTHONPATH="/your/custom/path:$PYTHONPATH"`).